# I am making a quiz app when i pressing the answer A,B,C,D it was not showing the next one

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a quiz app when I pressing the answer it was not showing the next question directly it was going to done activity where the score of the quiz will be displayed. Please tell me what to do and the changes i have to made for it. Please tell me in detail and which line the problem causes, because I am still learning, plz And also suggest me some improvements.

```
public class Playing extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final static long INTERVAL = 1000; // 1sec = 1000
    final static long TIMEOUT = 7000;  // 7000 = 7sec
    int progressValue = 0;

    CountDownTimer mCountDown;

    int index = 0, score = 0, thisQuestion = 0, totalQuestion, correctAnswer;


    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView question_image;
    Button btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD;
    TextView txtScore, txtQuestionNum, question_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playing);


        //View
        txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
        txtQuestionNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotalQuestion);
        question_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        question_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.question_image);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerA);
        btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerB);
        btnC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerC);
        btnD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerD);


        btnA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnC.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnD.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        mCountDown.cancel();
        if (index < totalQuestion) //still have question in List
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
            if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.questionList.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {

                //Choose correct answer
                score += 10;
                correctAnswer++;
                showQuestion(++index); //next question
            } else {
                //Choose wrong answer
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Done.class);
                Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
                dataSend.putInt("SCORE", score);
                dataSend.putInt("TOTAL", totalQuestion);
                dataSend.putInt("CORRECT", correctAnswer);
                intent.putExtras(dataSend);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showQuestion(int index) {
        if (index < totalQuestion) {
            thisQuestion++;
            txtQuestionNum.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d / %d", thisQuestion, totalQuestion));
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressValue = 0;
            if (Common.questionList.get(index).getIsImageQuestion().equals("true")) {
                //if is image
                Picasso.get().load(Common.questionList.get(index).getQuestion()).into(question_image);
                question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                question_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                question_text.setText(Common.questionList.get(index).getQuestion());
                //If question is text,we will set image to invisible
                question_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                question_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            btnA.setText(Common.questionList.get(index).getAnswerA());
            btnB.setText(Common.questionList.get(index).getAnswerB());
            btnC.setText(Common.questionList.get(index).getAnswerC());
            btnD.setText(Common.questionList.get(index).getAnswerD());
            mCountDown.start(); //Start timer
        } else {
            //If it is final question
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Done.class);
            Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
            dataSend.putInt("SCORE", score);
            dataSend.putInt("TOTAL", totalQuestion);
            dataSend.putInt("CORRECT", correctAnswer);
            intent.putExtras(dataSend);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        totalQuestion = Common.questionList.size();
        mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(TIMEOUT, INTERVAL) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long minisec) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
                progressValue++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mCountDown.cancel();
                showQuestion(++index);
            }
        };
        showQuestion(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have few questions here: Is this a Adapter class? I mean what's the purpose of `implements View.OnClickListener`? Also, can't find <ArrayList> Are you using SqlLite? Is this full code?

Comment: I am not using `SqlLite` and this is the full code of a activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no onClickListener within your Activity. I would recommend creating a "next()" function, and then, for each of the buttons, do something along the lines of:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   next()
})
```

Comment: Note: that is not the exact code. Android Studio will autogenerate OnClickListener when you start typing that in.